# docker list only most recent image

Tags: docker

Is there a way for docker to list only the most recent image made?
The documentation for `docker images` implies that there is a `--filter` flag but after searching I could not come up with a way to use it in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker images` output already formatted with descending order.

So you can just use something like follows to get the most recent image:

```
docker images | head -2
```

Output like follows:

```
REPOSITORY                TAG            IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
python                    2.7            3c43a5d4034a        9 days ago          908MB
```

And this is the [docker filter usage](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/10c0af083544460a2ddc2218f37dc24a077f7d90/docs/reference/commandline/images.md#filtering), seems can not make your aims.

Answer (score 0):

If you want most recent tag, you could use this. `--format` uses Golang formatting.

```
docker images --format='{{.Tag}}' | head -1
```

Or,

```
docker images --format='{{.ID}}' | head -1
```